# Add more than 1 non category link to top nav Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, menu

I Have the following PHP code and I'm trying **add more then 1 link to the to nav** but the code only display "Test page" and doesn't show "Test page2". I'm assuming I've coded it wrong so anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php
namespace testMod\navUpdate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Topmenu implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    $tree = $menu->getTree();
    $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page'),
        'id'        => 'test-page',
        'url'       => 'test-page',
    ];
    $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
    $menu->addChild($node);
    return $this;
}

public function execute2(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $data = [
            'name'      => __('Test page2'),
            'id'        => 'test-page2',
            'url'       => 'test-page2',
        ];
        $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($node);
        return $this;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Could you post the XML file that declare the observers please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Magento 2 observers **have only one method that will get executed** and it is the `execute` method.

So in your case only the `execute()` method is being executed that's why you don't get your second link from your `execute2()` method.

The solution is to update your `execute()` method with the code of your `execute2` method:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    $tree = $menu->getTree();
    $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page'),
        'id'        => 'test-page',
        'url'       => 'test-page',
    ];
    $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
    $menu->addChild($node);
    $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page2'),
        'id'        => 'test-page2',
        'url'       => 'test-page2',
    ];
    $node = new Node($data, 'id2', $tree, $menu);
    $menu->addChild($node);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: when I try and add a third link it only displays the first and last link any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Comment: @user3557071 please create a new issue with the following code, it'll be easier than just talk about it in the comments

Comment: forgot i created it yesterday: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116936/magento-2-non-category-links-not-displaying