# Magento 2 non-category links not displaying

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to add non category links to the top nav using the following code. It displays "Test page" & "Test page3" but not "Test page2". So I'm assuming that there is something wrong with the code as it display the first and last. Any ideas?

```
<?php
namespace atharna\navUpdate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Topmenu implements ObserverInterface
 {

/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
   /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
   $menu = $observer->getMenu();
   $tree = $menu->getTree();
   $data = [
       'name'      => __('Test page'),
       'id'        => 'test-page',
       'url'       => 'test-page',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   $data = [
       'name'      => __('Test page2'),
       'id'        => 'test-page2',
       'url'       => 'test-page2',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id2', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page3'),
        'id'        => 'test-page3',
        'url'       => 'test-page3',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id3', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   return $this;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: What if you move the part of the code that adds the "TEst page 2" after the code that adds "Test page 3" ?

Comment: I now see "Test page2" and not "Test page3"

Comment: That means that's not a bug with the code. It sounds like a CSS bug. Please inspect the source code using firebug or Chrome developer tools and see if the menu link is here but just hidden

Comment: Only 2 of the three links are displaying in the source code. No hidden elements are there

Comment: When you say move the add bit which parts should I be moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem.

They all need to have the same 'id' within the new node()